# Keyboard not working after login after update to 18.04

Tags: keyboard, login, 18.04

After upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04 my keyboard suddenly stopped working when logged in via Gnome(also tried the other two options, gnome with wayland and unity)
During login screen the keyboard is working though and i can change to a terminal via ctrl+alt+Fx.
But once i login only the touchpad is working, i also tried plugging in an external keyboard, or connecting a bluetooth mouse wich is shown as being connected but not working.
The model is a latitude E7440.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try this: click on "Activities" (top left corner). Once the "overview" appears, see if you can type Alt-F2 with your keyboard. If you are fortunate enough to get his far, type the letter "r" and press the Enter key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, check if Slow Keys is turned off in the Accessibility menu on the top right.
If it's already turned off, try:

```
    sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

If it's already installed, reinstall it:

```
    sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-all
    sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Comment: Turning off slow keys solved it for me.

Comment: Thxs. Can some explain this fix? When I ran my weekly `apt dist-upgrade` on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and rebooted I ran into this problem where everything worked on the login screen but as soon as I logged in (as either of two users), both mouse and keyboard got non-responsive. The GUI was still running, e.g. clock updating and difference software were loading up during startup. I had to access machine via SSH and installed `xserver-xorg-input-all`. After rebooting, it all worked again. What dark magic took place here? Did my `dist-upgrade` drop `xserver-xorg-input-all` breaking things, or ...?!?

Answer (score 6):

Turn on the on-screen keyboard (accessibility menu). After that perhaps the command "sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all" will do it.

Comment: @Rogerg not worked for me `xserver-xorg-input-all is already the newest version (1:7.7+19ubuntu7).` the application already installed. Would you tell me what other issue,?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this by turning off 'slow keys' in the dropdown menu in accessibility (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: Please check this out first! Happened to me as well. So annoying!

Comment: @sawablo I wrote this helping a friend at the University, [The model is a latitude E7440.] I just do not remember how we solved this ATM, Thanks

Comment: For me it was this setting issue!