# Keyboard wired not faunctioning on ubuntu 23.04

Tags: server, keyboard, application-development

I upgraded Ububtu 22.04 to 22.10 then to new released ubuntu 23.04 and it found that some times the Keyboard(USB) not functioning after unlocking to desk top.After restarting the machine it is found working. More the virtual keyboard is working but the enter key is not working,so I am facing much difficulties to perform the terminal work, Please find the way out to overcome this problem

Comment: Any one to help me?

Answer (score 0):

After a new update, the driver might not work (I’ve been told every major update, but I am new to Ubuntu, so I cannot confirm this).

Sometimes turning off slow keys will fix it.

One could try installing the driver again.

Click `Ctr + Alt + F3` to open the terminal. Next, try the below commands.

If the keyboard doesn’t work (in your case it does), use the mouse to enable the onscreen keyboard. Then right click and select the terminal.

On Ubuntu 18.04 at least, one can enable the onscreen keyboard by clicking the accessibility/human icon, the clicking the tool icon, the  going to the Universal Access section and finally, enabling it.

If the mouse and keyboard doesn’t work (in your case it does), restart the computer and hold shift after the BIOS or UEFI is loaded and before Ubuntu is done) booting. It should open the GRUB menu. Click e to edit boot options.

Search for the line that looks like:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-25-generic root=UUID=a98c605-2ac4-4ee3-8070-2560255293fe ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

Insert “/bin/bash” before $vt_handoff and press Ctrl + X or F10 to reboot. Once you in the command, run the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

If it is still installed, try:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-all
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Reboot the computer. If it doesn’t work, try using a different operating system than switching back to Ubuntu.

[Easy Cloud Solutions](https://techtips.easycloudsolutions.com/2020/01/18/how-to-fix-keyboard-not-working-after-ubuntu-update/#:%7E:text=The%20keyboard%20input%20driver%20breaks,input%20X%20Server%27s%20driver%20again.)

[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198142/1713591)

Answer (score 0):

I just open the bios of megabite and enable the usb keyboard the the problem is resolved

Comment: Right you are ,I have done asked for and the problem was resolved